# python regex match number followed by string or nothing

Tags: python, regex

how to match a number followed immediately by either /tcp or /udp or nothing?

the following illustrates 3 scenarios: input --> result

1. 123/tcp_haha --> 123
2. 123  --> 123
3. 123abc/tcp --> no match

i used `re.compile(r'(\d+)(?:\/[tcpud]{3})*')`but it also matched in case 3.

EDIT:
Guess it's really a follow up question: how to match digits either followed by /tcp or /udp or proceeded by tcp/ or /udp or just by itself?
so

```
 1.    something else 123/tcp_haha --> 123
 2.    123  --> 123
 3.    123abc/tcp --> no match
 4.    udp/123 something else --> 123
 5.    tcp/123/tcp --> 123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character class will match any combinations of its included characters. You need to use a logical OR instead.

```
r'^\d+(?:/tcp|/udp)?$'
```

`?:` is a non-capture group notation and `?` will make your non-capture group optional (for non-suffix cases).

If you want to capture the string if something followed the `/tcp` you can use following regex:

```
r'^\d+(?:/tcp.*|/udp)?$'
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oUm0e9/1

Comment: thanks for the reply! i just updated the post, realizing that i also want to capture the number even if something follows /tcp. how to achieve that? thanks again

Comment: hi @kas thanks for the reply again. I added a follow up question would be great if you could have a look. if it's too involved, i'll move it to a separate question.

Comment: @dragon_cat Just add the same thing to the leading. `r'^(?:tcp/|udp/)?\d+(?:/tcp.*|/udp)?$'`

Comment: yes, i have `re.compile(r'(?:.*tcp/|.*udp/)?(\d+)(?:/tcp.*|/udp.*)?$')`, but this requires both left and right to be either /tcp /udp or none. it will not match say `apple123/tcp`, which i would like to match.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for your original problem:

```
^\d+(?=/tcp|/udp|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/BUCTzW/1) after your edit:

```
\d+(?=\/tcp|\/udp)
```

- `\d+` matches one or more digit
- `(?=...)` is a lookahead, match will stop if next characters are ...
- `\/tcp|\/udp` matches a slash followed by `tcp` or `udp`

Comment: thanks for the reply! it works except fails to match all numbers (case 2)